# VMWARE ESX 4.1 HOST is not responding

Tags: vmware

My problem was that one VMWARE ESX 4.1 host was not responding. I have one cluster with 2 hosts. I've checked the logs. I had a disconnection of around 10 seconds.

The log is here:

```
VMWare 

* The host certificate chain is not complete.
[2012-04-19 09:00:20.058 02376 warning 'Libs'] SSLVerifyCertAgainstSystemStore: The remote host certificate has these problems:

* The host certificate chain is not complete.
[2012-04-19 09:00:20.058 02376 warning 'Libs'] SSLVerifyCertAgainstSystemStore: The remote host certificate has these problems:

* The host certificate chain is not complete.
[2012-04-19 09:12:15.683 02560 warning 'VpxProfiler' opID=HB-host-44@61962] [VpxdHostSync] GetChanges host:10.45.15.61 (10.45.15.61) took 2266 ms
[2012-04-19 09:12:16.089 02560 warning 'VpxProfiler' opID=HB-host-44@61962] [VpxdHostSync] DoHostSync:00000000062FEA00 took 2672 ms
[2012-04-19 09:12:16.089 02560 warning 'VpxProfiler' opID=HB-host-44@61962] InvtHostSyncLRO::StartWork took 2672 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:44.328 05220 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] ***WARNING*** Lock domain-c103 mode EXCLUSIVE held for 5328 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:44.328 06096 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking domain-c103 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 5317 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:44.343 00644 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking host-44 in mode: SHARE took 3880 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:47.640 06096 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] ***WARNING*** Lock domain-c103 mode EXCLUSIVE held for 3311 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:47.640 00644 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking host-28 in mode: SHARE took 1430 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.015 01604 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking host-44 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 8556 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.015 05220 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] ***WARNING*** Lock host-44 mode EXCLUSIVEALL held for 10016 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.015 05220 warning 'VpxProfiler'] InvtHostSyncLRO::StartWork took 10016 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.015 01180 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking vm-85 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 7713 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.015 05252 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking vm-39 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 8713 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.281 02556 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking host-44 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 9970 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.296 00388 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking host-44 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 9526 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.359 02376 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking host-28 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 3145 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.359 02444 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking vm-170 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 3270 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.359 06096 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] ***WARNING*** Lock host-28 mode EXCLUSIVEALL held for 10346 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.359 06096 warning 'VpxProfiler'] InvtHostSyncLRO::StartWork took 10359 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.359 03568 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking vm-335 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 2258 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.375 13812 warning 'VpxdMoLock'] Locking host-28 in mode: EXCLUSIVE took 4445 ms
[2012-04-19 09:19:49.984 00388 warning 'VpxProfiler'] VpxdMoAlarmManager::CheckAndFireAlarms took 10312 ms
[2012-04-19 10:00:44.546 01292 error 'App'] [Vdb::Connection::Commit] Connection commit failed: -1. Start retrying 20 more times.
[2012-04-19 10:00:47.781 01292 error 'App'] [Vdb::Connection::Commit] Connection commit failed: -1. Start retrying 20 more times.
[2012-04-19 10:01:20.781 02376 warning 'Libs'] SSLVerifyCertAgainstSystemStore: The remote host certificate has these problems:
```

It seems like it may have been a problem in the vCenter DB, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know, or have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the vCenter database, but I don't see anything in your log that indicates a database problem. What seems more likely is a network problem between your host and the vCenter Server.

Start with the basics. Do you have two physical NICs on your ESX host connected to your Management Network on seperate vSwitches and separate physical switches (pSwitches)? Are there any events in vCenter for the host that indicate disconnect? How about logs on the pSwitch?

Look at your networking before going to the database. Unless there is some database corruption, and then you would see many more issues, I would not look there yet.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for reply. First, I've got connected two physical NICs to our Management Network, each host of VM cluster has got two NICS. One virtual switch per two pNICS. Physical NIC is connecting to our CORE switches - A, B to has got a redundancy. vSwitch0 (serviceConsole has got IP address + serviceConsoleNetwork) -> Two pNICS -> Cisco Core Switch A and B. I"m going to check our core switches, if do I have some logs (network interuption). Thanks for reply

Comment: Do you manage the pSwitches? Can you or the network admin see any drops on the physical ports?

Comment: OA-Core_A#sh interfaces gigabitEthernet 3/29
GigabitEthernet3/29 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/2000/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 4794423. This is the sh run in cisco core. What do you recommend to deal with this problem?

Comment: For clarification, the ESX host was disconnected for apporximately 10 seconds and is currently connected and available in vSphere?

Comment: Yes, Uther exactly. Do you have other suggestions what was that?